# How to set up RabbitMQ default queue type to quorum queue on bootstrap?

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, quorum

I am trying to install a RabbitMQ cluster on Kubernetes using offical docker image `rabbitmq:3.12.5-alpine`. I have a init container from where I am overriding the default configurations.

I can see RabbitMQ uses classic mirrored queue by default if a client creates a queue to publish into the nodes. But, This does not ensures persistence without setting certain policies through cli. The data gets deleted once a pod restarts. I want to set quorum queue to be default queue type for the cluster. Is there any way to override this setting from configuration file/environment variable when bootstrapping the cluster? I have checked out the official documentation but could not find any. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can either create a custom image based on your config , or use init container , or use `command` and `args` section in your k8s manifest to add your own arguments . making volumes for the config files might help as well

Comment: also i have seen the docs and it mentions that config file locations can be seen in the env , see the value for `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILES` and `RABBITMQ_CONFIG_FILE` and test if persisting these files will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have checked out the official documentation but could not find any

Actually, the official documentation does answer your question:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/quorum-queues.html#declaring

> To declare a quorum queue set the `x-queue-type` queue argument to `quorum` (the default is `classic`). This argument must be provided by a client at queue declaration time; it cannot be set or changed using a policy.

Since this is a per-queue setting that happens at declaration time, there is currently **no way** to globally make all queues quorum queues.

Answer (score 1):

You can set default queue type for vhost
https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html#metadata

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost qa1 --description "QA environment 1" --default-queue-type quorum --tags qa,project-a
```